# removal of food in cart, but certain foods are not removing? why

Tags: c++

Here is my main:

```
int main() {
  Inventory Master;
  bool flag;
  Customer Bob("Bob", "CreditCard.txt");
  Customer Joe("Joe", "CreditCard.txt" );



  Master.firststock( "inventory.txt" );
  vector<Food> temp = Master._Inv;
  cout <<"Hi, What would you like to buy today?" << endl;
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++ ) {
    cout << temp[i].name << " " << temp[i].quant << " " << temp[i].price << endl;
  }

  cout <<"\n";
  Food Apple("Apples", .99, 10);
  Food Orange("Oranges", .99, 10);
  Food Chip("Chips", 3.00, 10);

  cout <<"\nHi Bob" << endl;
  flag = Bob.addCart(Apple, 7, &Master);
  cout <<"Bob's total purchases are Currently: \n";
  Bob.report();
  flag = Bob.addCart(Orange, 2, &Master);
  flag = Bob.addCart(Chip, 2, &Master);
  Bob.report();
  flag = Bob.removeCart();
   Bob.report();
  cout <<"Bob, ";
  flag = Bob.checkout(&Master);
```

here is the following i implemented to remove food from my vector _Cart:

```
bool Customer::removeCart() {
  bool flag;
  int q = 0;
  unsigned int i=0;
  string remove;

  cout << "\nWhat would you like to remove and how much would you like to remove?" << endl;
  cin >> remove >> q;
 for (i =0; i < _Cart.size(); i++) {
  if(remove == _Cart[i].name) {
      if (q >= 0) {
    _Cart[i].quant -= q;
    //inv->_Inv[i].quant += q;
    cout <<"\nYou removed " << q << " " << remove <<" In your cart\n" << endl;
    return true;
      }
      if  (q < 0) {
          cout << "Invalid number of " << remove << " being removed.\n" << endl;
          return true;
      }
  }
  else {      
  try {
    throw remove;
}

  catch (string param) {
    cout << "\n" << remove << " doesn't exist in your cart\n" << endl;
        }

        return true;
    }
 }
```

My header containing the the function removeCart:

```
class Customer {
  public:

   Customer(string n, string fileName);
    ~Customer() { _Cart.clear(); };
    bool addCart(Food f, int q, Inventory* inv);
    bool removeCart();
    void report(); 
    bool checkout(Inventory* inv); 
  protected:
    string remove;
    string name;
    int q;
    int card;
    double balance;
    CreditCard _CC(int card,double balance);
    vector<Food> _Cart;
};
```

Now for some reason when i call removeCart, entering "Apples" works but i noticed i made a food object called Apple so not sure why typing "Apples" works for being removed instead of "Apple". Also when i try "Orange" or "Chip" the exception is shown but as you can see in main i added Chip and Orange to Bob's Cart. I have even tried "Oranges" and "Chips" and it still throws me the exception instead of working. I could appreciate the help.

Comment: Your source is not a complete program, so, ehm, you are using `std::string` and `std::vector`, right? I'm just asking because I don't see any `#include` of `using namespace`, so it could be anything.

Comment: I mean i could include the whole program, if you would like. I just did provide everything for certain reasons but i can if need be. Shall I?

Comment: You need to include *less* code. Just a small, compilable sample that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for/if/else structure is broken. If you don't match on the first element in the cart, you throw an exception, which you immediately catch. Try something more like this:

```
 for (i =0; i < _Cart.size(); i++)
 {
    if(remove == _Cart[i].name)
    {
        if (q >= 0)
        {
           _Cart[i].quant -= q;
           //inv->_Inv[i].quant += q;
           cout <<"\nYou removed " << q << " " << remove <<" In your cart\n" << endl;
        }
        else
           cout << "Invalid number of " << remove << " being removed.\n" << endl;
        return true;
    }
 }
 cout << "\n" << remove << " doesn't exist in your cart\n" << endl;
 return true;
```

Comment: how could i fix that then? i mean i am still new to the exception handling.

Comment: See my update. You need to complete the `for` loop to finish searching for the item to be removed. It's not an error if it doesn't match the first item.

Comment: Ok yep that actually worked. I was missing a bit there. One question though. Lets say i throw an exception because the user input a food to be removed that wasn't in the cart how could i ask them to enter a food again to remove until its something that finally exists in the cart? A hint would do or some example if you could. If not i understand

Comment: Put the function, starting with selecting a food through to remove it, in a loop. Break out of the loop (say, by returning) when an item is removed successfully. Otherwise, just let it loop again.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a homework? :)

Firstly, "Apple" is the name of the variable you created, but you are passing "Apples" to the constructor of Food, so I suppose that this value is being assigned to its "name" member which is used in comparison.

Secondly, as David noticed, your loop will work only if you try to remove the first element in the cart. In your case the first element is named "Apples", so typing "Apples" works.

Comment: No its actually a project but its the one and only project in the class for the whole semester. But yeah i finally understood that it would only remove the first element. took me awhile i am slow. :D